# Merging an SQL query from a third table to an existing query that counts from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that *counts* calls and failed calls from two different tables from Nov 11 to Nov 24, 2013 for each client.

```
SELECT d.id_client,
   d.login,
   Coalesce(c.total, 0)  AS calls,
   Coalesce(fc.total, 0) AS calls_failed
FROM   api.clients d
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS total,
                           id_client
                    FROM   voip.calls c
                    WHERE  c.call_start >= '2013-11-11 00:00:00'
                           AND c.call_start < '2013-11-25 00:00:00'
                    GROUP  BY id_client) c
                ON d.id_client = c.id_client
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Count(*) AS total,
                           id_client
                    FROM   voip.callsfailed c
                    WHERE  c.call_start >= '2013-11-11 00:00:00'
                           AND c.call_start < '2013-11-25 00:00:00'
                           AND c.ie_error_number <> 0
                    GROUP  BY id_client) fc
                ON d.id_client = fc.id_client
    WHERE  d.id_client IN (SELECT e.idclient
                   FROM   voip.invoiceclients e
                   WHERE  e.clientnr = 'demo')
```

I have a separate query that provides client_balance, mobile_number, name for each client.

```
SELECT cr.id_client,
   inv.taxid AS company,
   inv.name,
   inv.lastname,
   inv.mobilephone,
   cr.account_state
FROM   clientsretail cr,
   invoiceclients inv
WHERE  cr.id_client = inv.idclient
   AND inv.clientnr = 'demo'
ORDER  BY inv.taxid,
      inv.name;
```

How can I merge these queries to produce the following output:
id_client,Company,Name,Lastname,Mobilephone,Login,Calls,Failed,calls,Balance

*I tried to take some baby steps with the following query, but failed:*

```
SELECT d.id_client, d.login,
COALESCE(c.total, 0) AS calls, COALESCE(fc.total, 0) AS calls_failed
FROM api.clients d
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, id_client
    FROM voip.calls c
    WHERE c.call_start >= '2013-11-11 00:00:00'
      AND c.call_start < '2013-11-25 00:00:00'
    GROUP BY id_client
) c ON d.id_client = c.id_client
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total, id_client
    FROM voip.callsfailed c
    WHERE c.call_start >= '2013-11-11 00:00:00'
      AND c.call_start < '2013-11-25 00:00:00'
      AND c.IE_error_number <> 0
    GROUP BY id_client
) fc ON d.id_client = fc.id_client
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT c.idclient,
      c.taxid,
      c.name,
      c.lastname,
      c.mobilephone
    FROM voip.invoiceclients c
) v ON d.id_client=v.idclient
WHERE d.id_client IN
(
SELECT e.idclient
FROM voip.invoiceclients e
WHERE e.clientnr='demo'
)
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
 'FROM voip.invoiceclients c
) v ON d.id_client=v.idclient WHERE d.id_clie' at line 28
```

Comment: Seems like you'd just wrap that second query in parens, and `LEFT JOIN  (subquery) v ON v.id_client = d.client_id`, and reference columns from that inline view (aliased as v) in the SELECT list of the outer query... `SELECT d.id_client, v.company, v.name, ... `.  Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: ON your edit you have left a `,` after `c.mobilephone` on your V subquery. Plus with this edit you dont need the where clause just put it on the V subquery: `FROM voip.invoiceclients c WHERE c.clientnr='demo'`

Comment: I end up getting way too many results if I moved the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct,There is a small syntax error only.Just remove the comma(',') after c.mobilephone in the select statement,your syntax error problem will be solved and query will run.